# Using a content script with 127.0.0.1 and a custom port with a Firefox Addon

Tags: selenium, firefox, integration-testing, firefox-addon-webextensions, geckodriver

I want to test a ported Firefox Addon with Selenium, as I'm already doing with Google Chrome. This extension works with a custom website and the development version of this website is serve under 127.0.0.1:9000. I need to work with content scripts, but they are not injecting in my page whereas they inject in the production version of my service.

I searched in the documentation of Web Extensions, but the only thing I found is that [I should not mention the port number of my webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#host). I tried to remove the port from my manifest, but it's still not injecting. When I use a Nginx config to map my service to a local domain with no port, it works. Unfortunately it's not possible for me to use an Nginx config on my CI, I need to work with 127.0.0.1.

Here is a subset of my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:9000/*",
        "https://example.org/*",
      ],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

My content script will interact with `https://example.org/` but not with `http://127.0.0.1:9000/`... (this works perfectly with Chrome)

Is there any way to make a content script interact with 127.0.0.1 and a custom port?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me just now, just leave off the port number.

```
"matches": ["http://127.0.0.1/*"]
```

It's mentioned in on of the notes in the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns (search for `1234` to go directly to the note)